# I am making an autoclicker, and I need to customize it to click only when I hold the mouse key down

Tags: c++

I would go into Codeblocks, and I would simply put something like this.

```
while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) {
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The problem with this code is: It keeps sending LButton, so the program continues, and it doesn't stop clicking. I was wondering if there is a way to differentiate between real mouse clicks and virtual mouse clicks.

Comment: Kevin Duarte It has the same issue. If you are going to use if on a loop like that, it is just like a while statement. I tried it, and it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but here you go! Note: I did not optimize it in any shape or form so you may need to modify it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {

                keybd_event(VK_LBUTTON, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
                {
                    keybd_event(VK_LBUTTON, 0x45, 0, 0);
                    std::cout << "Click" << std::endl;
                }
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that exclamation mark before GetAsyncKeyState? I see that it works, but I don't get why putting the virtual code for 'E' works with VK_LBUTTON? Why didn't an error come up when you tried to compile it?

Comment: @SharkFooth I think I may have posted my answer too soon. The click only works SOMETIMES. I may need to see how to fix it. The exclamation point means if the key is NOT being held. None the less, you can switch out the part where it says "Click" with a function that clicks for you

Comment: @SharkFooth The `!` is the "logical NOT" operator, it flips a value's truthiness.  `!true == false` and `!false == true`.  Since `GetAsyncKeyState()` returns a `short` (meaning `0` is `false` and non-zero is `true`), `!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)` is effectively shorthand for `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) == 0` in this case.